# c# find and replace urls from string with regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

i want to replace url for example www.google.com or http://www.google.com with www.google.com i have a code for this

```
str = Regex.Replace(str,
                @"((http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)",
                "<a target='_blank' href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

it is working with `http://www.google.com` but it is not working with `www.google.com` or `subdomain.google.com` which regex code matches with every url links. and when i wrote a long link it will write same of the url for example

```
http://www.google.com/search/asdadad/sdsdsd/sadasdx-sadasd-weqeqwe-zxcxzc.com
```

. i want to write it as

`<a href="http://www.google.com/search/asdadad/sdsdsd/sadasdx-sadasd-weqeqwe-zxcxzc.com">google.com/asdas... </a>`

what is the best way to make this? i am new for regex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will also catch `www.test.com`:

```
(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;\/~\+#])?)
 ↑---------------------↑↑
```

Just surround the part thats optional and append a questionmark.
You can check it out [here.](https://regex101.com/r/uB9oD4/1)

---

The first match in this regex (matches are defined with "(" and ")") is the whole url. So you could use replacing like this:

```
Regex rgxUrls = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgxUrls.Replace(yourText, "<a href=\"$1\"> space for custom text </a>");
                                                      ↑ Inserts first match
```

[image]

Where I've used `$1` you can also use `$2 - $5`. Check the image above thats showing which groups are capturing which part of the url.

**Full test can be found** [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQUl2WF93enRmbXM).
Just click **execute** on the top.

Output:
[image]

---

**According the comments, how group caption works:**

```
Text: "this is your text to search"  
Pattern: "text to"
```

Match[0] will always match your whole match `text to`. Every groups above like `Match[1]` or `Match[2]` has to be defined with "(" and ")".

```
Text: "this is your text to search"  
Pattern: "text (to)"  
Match[0]: "text to"  
Match[1]: "to"  


Pattern: "text (t(o))"  
Match[0]: "text to"  
Match[1]: "to"  
Match[2]: "o"
```

The caption with "()" works from the outside to the inside.

```
$1
(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;\/~\+#])?)
↑--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------↑

$2 (http://)
(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;\/~\+#])?)
 ↑---------------------↑

$3 (http)
(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;\/~\+#])?)
  ↑--------------↑

$4 (.com)
(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;\/~\+#])?)
                                 ↑----------↑   

$5 (/appendedSubdirectory/anotherOne)
(((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;\/~\+#])?)
                                              ↑--------------------------------------------------↑
```

I cant explain everything about regex in here. This question looks solved for me. If you've got deeper questions according regex start a new one and show some effort you've done before.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i have to learn to edit match value. $1 is getting full adress. i want to edit $1 for example matched_value.Substring(0,5) what is the right way ?

second question : the url www.google.com found and replaced by your code but the link is without http. so when i clicked link it will show mydomain.com/www.google.com how can i add link with http

Comment: You want to replace `www.google.de` with `http://www.google.de`? I will edit my question and explain group caption.

Comment: thanks for your helpful answer. I will update my code with your suggestions.